# DAX mean and return result in SD +-N range

Tags: powerbi, dax

i want to store a table of variables with mean and SD [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOzvB.png)

then i have raw data that i need to calculate which SD range does my result falls in
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60JgJ.png)

I want a column return my result range "+1 SD" / "-1 SD" / "-2 SD" / "+2 SD" / "+3 SD"

i also dont want to write long DAX formula and i want to make it dynamic, when i change the SD and mean, i want to auto refresh my calculation and result range

i dont know how to write a dynamic calculation formula

Comment: Dynamic columns are not possible in Power BI. Perhaps revise your requirements.

Comment: You may want to get the better understanding of PowerBI fundamentals. e.g. “… when i change the SD and mean, i want to auto refresh my calculation and result range…” - it depends on what you mean by changing. In principle, it is possible what you want to do, except Power BI only supports the user to select and filter from what is predefined or calculated by the tables, columns and to get additional results from measures (There is some advanced work-around to also enter data back into your model, but it’s not the original purpose of Power BI).

Comment: For the logic between the 2 tables as outlined by you, might be enough to have a calculated column with the resulting SD “category” (e.g. depending on what you mean by “changing” the SD and mean values). If it requires calculation during the interaction with the visual(s), and not just choosing from pre-calculated values, then you need to use a measure. Good luck!